How can the constitutional court enforce rulings on the father of the house?
In September 2024 in Thuringia, Germany, the father of the house (Alterspräsident in German; a member of AfD), presiding over the inaugural session, was accused by all other fractions of violating the constitution, after refusing to allow a debate or a vote on changing the rules of order.  The conservative party (CDU) then asked the constitutional court to rule on the question if a newly elected parliament can implement such a change.  See this German language article on tagesschau.de and an English language blog article predicting drama.
Suppose the father of the house refuses to respect/implement this ruling (and refuses a vote on electing someone else to preside the inaugural session), what ways exist to enforce the ruling by the constitutional court?  Can he be forcibly removed from the presiding role if ignoring a court order?

The provisional ruling of the state constitutional court has now been published. At its core, the father of the house (as the defendant) is ordered to do the following:

Der Antragsgegner wird verpflichtet, bei der Fortsetzung der konstituierenden Sitzung des Thüringer Landtags den Namensaufruf der Abgeordneten durchzuführen, daran anknüpfend die Feststellung über die Beschlussfähigkeit des Landtags zu treffen und sodann die vorläufige Tagesordnung in der Fassung vom 19. September 2024 im Plenum zur Abstimmung zu stellen.


The defendant is obliged to call the names of the members of parliament at the continuation of the constituent session of the Thuringian State Parliament, to determine the quorum of the State Parliament and then to put the provisional agenda in the version of 19 September 2024 to the vote in plenary.

No other petition of the applicants has been granted.

@SMSTJ I'm in doubt where it fits better (multi-posting is not wanted on SE).  On second-thought, I have a weak preference for Law.SE, and I have flagged the question for migration.

Usually people just do what the supreme Court decides. If not... don't know. Civil war in Thuringia maybe?

While I think that this question is a great fit for politics stack exchange, I will respect the wish of the author and migrate it to law stack exchange.

There are some rules in the Bundestag allowing a member to be expelled for doing bad things, typically after a vote by the Ältestenrat (council of elders); I'm not sure if the Thuringian parliament has a similar rule.

Incidentally, it would help the question if you explicitly stated which specific legislature you're talking about.

You want to be serious but you know it's hard with AfD just being the destructive force here. What will happen? The supreme Court of Thuringia will decide today and tomorrow either the AfD will cooperate or it won't. If it won't, all predictions are off and we are in new territory. That's all from a non-law more political perspective.

The ruling of the constitutional court has now been published: https://verfassungsgerichtshof.thueringen.de/media/tmmjv_verfassungsgerichtshof/Entscheidungen/24-00036_Beschluss_nicht_barrierefrei.pdf

Not sure there is precedent for any of that, given that this is supposed to be more of a ceremonial role. So before the parliament elects a president the oldest or most senior member of parliament takes that role. So that person has neither a democratic mandate nor much power and is rather there as a master of ceremonies as someone needs to organize that and the older people usually have the most experience with protocols and and whatnot.
It is probably within his power to shut down hecklers and MPs overstepping the rules, but shutting down debates and proposals is actively sabotaging the work of parliament and the rights of the MPs which basically brought the inaugural session to a halt.
So according to a lawyer on constitutional matters he has definitely overstep his powers (german link), but might also have further violated the constitutional rights of the MPs. There are 2 opposing views on whether the self-organizing principle of parliament works before or after it's official constitution, but sabotaging it entirely is apparently massively overstepping the powers of an almost purely ceremonial position that does not have the same powers as an actual president of parliament.
Now how the court will decide will be seen, probably today already as they requested a speedy trial and the inaugural session is supposed to continue tomorrow so maybe just wait on how that will turn out.
And in terms of consequences well the minister of the interior already floated the proposal to ban the AfD (german link). Usually in that regard one distinguishes between merely holding views that are anti-constitutional views, which leads to further investigation, but is usually still covered by free speech and behavior that is actively aiming to work against the constitution. Where in this case sabotaging parliament probably adds a new bullet point to that list of evidence.
Also the AfD does not hold a majority in parliament so the rest could just elect a new president which they are supposed to do in the inaugural session anyway and he's definitely ramping up fines for violating laws of parliament but may even incriminate himself much further, but not a lawyer and we're likely going to see the results of that very soon anyway.
Update: Apparently the Thüringer Verfassungsgericht confirmed most of the points of the CDU, which includes the legality of what they were proposing as well as the autonomy of parliament to change the agenda for the day, to check if enough MPs are present to make changes and to change the organization of the election for president of parliament ahead of the election.
The point where they lost is to bind the Alterspräsident to hold a vote on the change of the rules of procedure, but apparently that's more of a technical issue, because so far they haven't gotten to the point where parliament had put that on the agenda and the MPs showed the will to do so, but as now the ability of parliament is reaffirmed and as there is apparently a majority, that shouldn't be necessary in the first place.
And they apparently gave the Alterspräsident a roadmap of how the next session is supposed to look like.
And apparently Treutner has acknowledged the ruling and promised to apply it.
Here are German links for the ruling by a legal blog:
https://www.lto.de/recht/nachrichten/n/nach-eskalation-im-thueringer-landtag-verfassungsgerichtshof-vgh-gibt-cdu-antragg-statt
As well as a live tracker for the session and the scandals around it:
https://www.mdr.de/nachrichten/thueringen/wahlen-politik/landtag-aktuell-live-ticker-konstituierung-start-sitzung-104.html?trk=public_post_comment-text

@haxor789 the current set of rules only talks about the strongest faction proposing a candidate, it never mentions what should happen if no candidate of the strongest faction is accepted. And that is the set of rules they want to keep.

The point does still stand that this answer does not answer the ACTUAl question

@SMSTJ As said there are no such constitutional provisions, that is merely the Geschäftsordnung des Thüringer Landtags https://www.thueringer-landtag.de/fileadmin/Redaktion/Organigramm_GO_Gesetze_Arbeitsplan/geschaeftsordnung_des_thueringer_landtags_02.pdf specifically §2 and it's within the powers of the Landtag to change that. The question is now whether the MPs as-is have the power to do so or whether they need to constitute before doing so. And that question is currently being decided and I am no lawyer. In the politics stack that's valuable information, hopefully legal can do me better.

@SMSTJ But I'd guess that the extend of the rule breaking and the decision of the supreme court plays a role in what can and is happening next. Like in case of a crime immunities can be revoked, regular presidents can be "re-called" (evicted from office), but maybe none or all of that becomes necessary depending on how the court decides what the order of operations is. Like as said I don't think there is much precedent for that as it's probably rare for things to get that heated before parliament even constitutes itself.

@SMSTJ Now according to this article https://www.lto.de/recht/hintergruende/h/bundesverfassungsgericht-resilienz-vollstreckung-bundeszwang-rechtsstaat-politik the supreme court (the federal) can decide for itself how it enforces it's rulings. Though usually there is no need for enforcement because the decisions are usually accepted, if that is not the case it can take various routes. Also as said unconstitutional behavior can lead to a ban of a party.

The Landtag having the power to change the Geschäftsordnung befor a President is elected is exactly the issue in contestion. And again: yes the court willl MOST LIEKELY come down against the AfD, but the questioner specifically asked WHAT the courts can do to enforce their ruling. Also, this will go to the Landesverfassungsgericht.

I suppose the threat of a party prohibition if the father of the house ignores the court ruling is probably enough pressure.

@SMSTJ I know it's a states supreme court not the federal one which is why I mentioned that to indicate the article might only partially or not at all apply. Though usually that's one of the questions that you don't want answers for because going through these routes already makes a mockery of democracy and pushes the power from the legislature to the Juridical branch, which might take longer, lacks a democratic mandate or encourages rough patching. Neither is good or what they are supposed to be.

@SMSTJ Also from the live ticker of events it seems that they didn't even get to making the vote but that the Alterspräsident had already interrupted the sessions several times to avoid a request to confirm that the house is in sufficient strength to decide over a proposal. So he already attacked the step before that.

@gerrit Given that the AfD doesn't hold the government or a parliamentary majority, there's a good chance that the other parties have the legal mandate to get around that especially if the courts have their back on that. It's something different if a government ignores the supreme court because that would largely enter into new domains that are technically mapped out but the damage to democracy could be tremendous and given how long courts take the events unfolding could outpace the court. Worst example would be the legal shenanigans of the NSDAP in 1933.
